# GitHub Actions - is there anywhere that lists them all?

Tags: github-actions

I'm not finding a list of all GitHub actions so struggling to find something really basic like an AWS GitHub action (other than Google'ing for it).

Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all of the Github Actions in Github's marketplace under the Actions filter. https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions